# Anchor text going outside div section

Tags: html, css

[image: link text image]

I have a element div and an anchor tag that displays it's name. It's text is going outside the div. How to control this text?

```html
<div class="col-md-6">
  <a style="border: 1px solid #d1d1d1;
    margin-top: 5px;
    padding: 10px;
    overflow: hidden;
    min-height: 345px;
    min-width: 221.46px !important;
    max-width: 230.46px !important;" href="http://localhost/hostname/MDLIncidentMgmt/IM_TicketDetail.aspx?ID=abcsfstw%3d%3d" target="_blank" class="notranslate">http://localhost/hostname/MDLIncidentMgmt/IM_TicketDetail.aspx?ID=abcsfstw%3d%3d
    </a>
</div>
```

Comment: In real scenario as I guess those long type of URL is not in use. please say why are you using those long URL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I understood that this is happening because you are doing this:

```
<a href="http://google.com">http://google.com</a>
```

Since in a link all everything is connected with each other this can't be separated normally. So you should use something like this instead of that:

```
<a href="http://google.com"> Link </a>
```

Or, you can also use a button here:

```
 <a href="http://google.com">
    <button class="btn btn-priamary">LINK</button>
 </a>
```

Or, if you certainly want to do as you have, you should do something like this:

```
<div style="width:200px">

    <a href="..." style="word-break: break-all;">
        https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61143433/anchor-text-going- 
        outside-div-section/61143889#61143889
    </a>

</div>
```

That'll solve your problem Insaallah.

Answer (score 1):

Not entirely sure what you are trying to accomplish but if you want it to just fit inside the div remove the width stuff and just make it inline-block since you cant apply width or height to inline elements which an anchor tag defaults to

```html
<div class="col-md-6"><a style="border: 1px solid #d1d1d1;
      margin-top: 5px;
      padding: 10px;
      display: inline-block;
      min-height: 345px;" href="http://localhost/hostname/MDLIncidentMgmt/IM_TicketDetail.aspx?ID=abcsfstw%3d%3d" target="_blank" class="notranslate">http://localhost/hostname/MDLIncidentMgmt/IM_TicketDetail.aspx?ID=abcsfstw%3d%3d</a></div>
```

Comment: anchor tag text going outside of div class-md-6, can you observe in image . Meaning the text is moved out of container div. anchor tag text should come bottom once width reached maximum.text should not go outside of border shown in image